# Navigating a 2D array mapped to 1D with boundary conditions

Tags: c, arrays, conways-game-of-life, sub-array

I'm attempting to implement the game of life with a focus on efficiency, as well functionality for pattern matching. Where patterns are blinkers, gliders, crosses, etc.

I've got a 1D array for the world, as well as a width and height. In order to find the neighbours I want to calculate the indices of the Moore neighbourhood, then check if these are hashes, if they are this increases the return variable for the get_neighbours function. North and south appears to work, but east and west do not. NE, SE, SW, NW are all based upon the previous logic (i.e. go north on west).

```
int get_neighbours(int loc) {
    int neighbours = 0;

    int n = mod(loc - grid_width, total);
    int e = mod(loc + 1, grid_width) + grid_width;
    int s = mod(loc + grid_width, total);
    int w = mod(loc - 1, grid_width) + grid_width;
    int nw = mod(w - grid_width, total);
    int ne = mod(e - grid_width, total);
    int se = mod(e + grid_width, total);
    int sw = mod(w + grid_width, total);

    //Northwest
    if (grid[nw] == '#') {
        neighbours++;
    }
    //North
    if (grid[n] == '#') {
        neighbours++;
    }
    //Northeast
    if (grid[ne] == '#') {
        neighbours++;
    }
    //East
    if (grid[e] == '#') {
        neighbours++;
    }
    //Southeast
    if (grid[se] == '#') {
        neighbours++;
    }
    //South
    if (grid[s] == '#') {
        neighbours++;
    }
    //Southwest
    if (grid[sw] == '#') {
        neighbours++;
    }
    //West
    if (grid[w] == '#') {
        neighbours++;
    }
    return neighbours;
}

int mod(int a, int b) {
    int ret = a % b;
    if (b < 0) {
        return mod(-a, -b);
    }
    else if (ret < 0) {
        ret += b;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

For the pattern matching, I attempted to use the same logic as above in order to build a 5x5 subarray. This essentially uses a "read head." Which steps through the world from the provided location east, until it has moved 5 spaces. Then, it returns to the original position and moves south the correct number of rows, before moving East again, until we have collected 25 indices.

```
char *get_subarray(int loc) {
    char *subarray;
    subarray = malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);

    int i = 0;
    int ptr = loc;

    while (i < 25) {
        subarray[i] = grid[ptr];
        if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0) {
            //return the read head to the original location, then travel south through the grid once for each of the times we have traversed a row
            ptr = loc;
            for (int k = 0; k <= (i / 5); k++) {
                ptr = mod(ptr + grid_width, total);
            }
        } else {
            ptr = mod(ptr + 1, grid_width) + grid_width;
        }
        i++;
    }
    subarray[i] = '\0';
    return subarray;

}
```

As it does so, it builds the subarray from the world, then I can strcmp() this against the string for a pattern.

```
int cpu_get_crosses() {
    int crosses = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        if (strcmp(get_subarray(i), "       #   # #   #       ") == 0) {
            crosses++;
        }
    }
    return crosses;
}
```

For reference, a 7x5 grid with indices (with boundaries):

```
34|28 29 30 31 32 33 34|28
--|--------------------|--
6 |0  1  2  3  4  5  6 |0
13|7  8  9  10 11 12 13|7 
20|14 15 16 17 18 19 20|14
27|21 22 23 24 25 26 27|21
34|28 29 30 31 32 33 34|28
--|--------------------|--
6 |0  1  2  3  4  5  6 |0
```

I'm curious as to what logic would allow me to calculate the indices for the Moore neighbourhood whilst preserving the boundary conditions, so that I can calculate neighbours and the subarray correctly (as these both would use the same logic).

**EDIT:** Subarray function if any googlers want it.

```
char *get_subarray(int loc) {
    char *subarray;
    subarray = malloc(sizeof(char) * 25); //5x5 (=25) subarray

    int i = 0;
    int row = loc / grid_width;
    int ptr = loc;

    while (i < 25) {
        subarray[i] = grid[ptr];
        if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0) {
            //return the read head to the original location, then travel south through the grid once for each of the times we have traversed a row
            ptr = loc;
            for (int k = 0; k <= (i / 5); k++) {
                ptr = mod(ptr + grid_width, total);
            }
            row = ptr / grid_width;
        } else {
            ptr = mod(ptr + 1, grid_width) + row * grid_width;
        }
        i++;
    }
    subarray[i] = '\0';
    return subarray;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Fjotten Oops. Early morning. Question edited.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Sorry about that, that was another error in copying and pasting as I was in the middle of messing with it. Checked over the post and there shouldn't be any more mistakes. Thanks for the efficiency tip, I'll check that out when I get a chance.

Comment: to fix your east and west calculations you first have to find out, on which row you're current location is: `int row = loc / grid_width;` now e.g. `e = mod(loc + 1, grid_width) + row * grid_width` (and similar for west)

Comment: @BeyelerStudios that... works! Thank you! Had to tweak it for the subarray function but it works. I swear I tried something like that but I must've been missing something; 12 hours days will make you stupid. If you wanna post an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're indexing your array in a row-wise fashion: `index(i, j) = j * grid_width + i` for `i=0..grid_width-1, j=0..grid_height-1`. Let's call `loc` the result of `index(i, j)` and reverse `index` to get `i` and `j`:

```
int i = loc % grid_width;
int j = loc / grid_width;
```

To go east increase `i` by one, to go west decrease by one, both modulo the width:

```
int e = j * grid_width + (i + 1) % grid_width
      = j * grid_width + ((j * grid_width + i) + 1) % grid_width
      = j * grid_width + (loc + 1) % grid_width;
int w = j * grid_width + (i + grid_width - 1) % grid_width
      = j * grid_width + ((j * grid_width + i) + grid_width - 1) % grid_width
      = j * grid_width + (loc + grid_width - 1) % grid_width;
```

Note:

1. `(i + grid_width - 1) % grid_width` is equal to `mod(i - 1, grid_width)`
2. `x % M = (k * M + x) % M` for any integral `k`, this let's us replace `i` in any expression modulo `grid_width` with `loc = j * grid_width + i` to avoid computing `i` in the first place ;)

Increasing `j` by one modulo the height is equal to adding `grid_width` and wrapping by `total` since `total` is width x height. Making it more explicit, here's the derivation:

```
int j1 = (j + 1) % grid_height;
int s = j1 * grid_width + i
      = ((j + 1) % grid_height) * grid_width + i
      = ((j + 1) * grid_width) % (grid_height * grid_width) + i
      = ((j + 1) * grid_width) % total + i
      = (j * grid_width + grid_width + i) % total
      = ((j * grid_width + i) + grid_width) % total
      = (loc + grid_width) % total;
// analogue for j0 = (j + grid_height - 1) % grid_height;
int n = (loc + total - grid_width) % total;
```